# How to fix these issues in Processing?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm a beginner of coding. I have encounter these two problem in learning Processing:

1. I can't use JavaScript mode in processing.When I change to JavaScript mode in processing, the IDE closed automatically. However, I check the program in task manager, I found that the javaw.exe is still running. I think it maybe the version problem.My processing version is 3.2.1
2. I can't save my file in processing.The error is that:
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdlCN.png)

Can anyone help me to fix these two issues?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use p5.js, while the main Processing editor is being developed, I recommend trying the [p5.js editor](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-editor/releases/download/v0.6.1/p5-win.zip) (direct download link for Windows)
It's simpler and iterated much faster than the main Processing IDE, so should be easier to get started.

Additionally, here are few great video tutorial resources for p5.js:

- [1-6: Foundations of Programming in JavaScript - p5.js Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8j0UDiN7my4&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA)
- [Introduction to Programming for the Visual Arts with p5.js](https://www.kadenze.com/courses/introduction-to-programming-for-the-visual-arts-with-p5-js/info)
- [The Nature of Code](https://www.kadenze.com/courses/the-nature-of-code/info)

[image: Introduction to Programming for the Visual Arts with p5.js title card]

[image: The Nature of Code title card]

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript mode isn't supported in Processing 3 yet. If you want to use the Processing editor, you'll have to download version 2.2.1.

**Edit:** I thought you were talking about Processing.js, but it looks like you're talking about p5.js. In that case, check out George's answer.

Answer (score -2):

For the saving question: I think that processing always delete all the old files before saving again the new ones. Maybe it could be a problem that you are not running it as administrator. Try that.